# SQLITE_ERROR: near "FROM": syntax error in Node.js

Tags: sql, express

I use express.js, sqlite and sequelize. I create a query with sequelize for the database(sqlite).
I got an error.

My query(By the way, i use string interpolation.):

```
UPDATE Cart_Products SET count = count + 1 FROM Cart_Products 
INNER JOIN Carts on Carts.id = Cart_Products.cartId 
INNER JOIN Users on Users.id = Carts.userId 
WHERE Carts.userId = ${req.params.userId} AND Cart_Products.productId = ${req.params.productId}
```

Comment: If you look at the syntax diagram in SQLite (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html), you'll see that it doesn't support `FROM`.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html shows meanwhile since version 3.33.0 (2020-08-14) that `UPDATE .. SET .. FROM ..` is supported. They even have now a chapter "UPDATE FROM".